# using phonegap and ionic together any comprehensive guide?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i have search on stackover flow,google and youtube didnt got any good resource for using phonegap with ionic  so dont consider it as a duplicate, i want to operate it with CLI commands so whether to use "ionic start" command or to "phonegap create"? and how to bridge the gap.
thanks in advance

Comment: You could also just create a PhoneGap app, then just manually include the Ionic JS and CSS files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an application using the Ionic CLI, by default it makes a Cordova project for you. You do not have to worry about making it with the PG or Cordova CLI. Just try it. Make a project w/ Ionic, open the folder, and you will see the Cordova assets as well. You can also manage platforms, plugins, and builds with the Ionic CLI too.

So to repeat (grin), making a project via Ionic makes a Cordova project. You can use it like you would any other Cordova project. Remember that when you want to add features, like Camera support, you need to add plugins, again, *exactly* like you do with Cordova.

Comment: will it have all camera api and features provided by phonegap with same code?

Comment: Yes. The Ionic CLI simply makes a new Cordova project for you. It *is* a Cordova project. Period. Don't overthink it. ;) Of course, the same rules apply - you have to add the Camera plugin before you use it.

Comment: oaky plz add this in answer so that i can accept is as a answer, and kindly eloborate about "ading plugin" thing, cant we use just javvascript code navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

Comment: Adobe Phonegap is a distribution of Apache Cordova, and Ionic creates a Cordova project. They are mostly the same, and share almost the same plugins, but there are slight (but maybe significant for you) differences between them. Anyway, with a little of effort, you could port your ionic project to phonegap anytime. You could read this for more info about Phonegap vs Cordova: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/